# Magento 2.4 Add custom language switcher in header

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I'm creating a custom header in Magento 2.4.4, I want to include language switcher but not the default dropdown view.

**I want to include link to the second language only.**

So if I have 2 languages English & French, in English I want to show only French at the header so when users click on it; it should takes them to the translated page not the home page.

[Screenshot of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RhvH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Zee we can create a language switcher by using phtml file in design folder like this
app/design/frontend/vendor/Module/Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml

```
<?php if (count($block->getStores())>1) : ?>
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
<div class="switcher language switcher-language" data-ui-id="language-switcher" id="switcher-language<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Language')) ?></span></strong>
    <?php
        $currentWebsite = $helper->getCurrentWebsiteName();
    ?>
    <?php if($currentWebsite == 'Qatar'){ ?>
        <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
            <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                 id="switcher-language-trigger<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>">
                <strong class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang) : ?>
                        <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()) : ?>
                            <strong class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>">
                                <span>
                                    <a class="language-switcher-link" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewModel()->getTargetStoreRedirectUrl($_lang)) ?>">
                                        <?php if($_lang->getName() == "Arabic"){ ?>
                                            <?= $block->escapeHtml("عربي") ?>
                                        <?php }else{ ?>
                                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </a>

                                </span>
                            </strong>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php  }else{ ?>
        <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
            <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                 id="switcher-language-trigger<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>"
                 data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                 data-toggle="dropdown"
                 data-trigger-keypress-button="true">
                <strong class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreName()) ?></span>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown"
                data-target="dropdown">
                <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang) : ?>
                    <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()) : ?>
                        <li class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()) ?> switcher-option">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewModel()->getTargetStoreRedirectUrl($_lang)) ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for archive your requirement

In the below answer I am assuming that you know how to get store data.

```
<?php
$currentStore = "English"; // THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC
$switchStore = "French"; // THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC
$URL = 'https://demo.com/product.html?___store='. $currentStore .'&amp;___from_store='.$switchStore
?>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='<?= $URL ?>'"> <?= __('STORE_NAME') ?></a>
```

Hope this will useful for you.

Thank you.